# How to filter a list of dates in order to retrieve weekly reports

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I have two datepickers. 03/05/2017 to 10/05/2017

Using those two dates, I want to generate weekly reports.

As a result, I expect:

- one report for 03/05/2017 - 07/05/2017
- one report for 08/05/2017 - 08/05/2017

The last day of the week should be considered as Sunday.

So I've added them in a list

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2017, 05, 03);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2017, 05, 10);

if (end < start)
    throw new ArgumentException("endDate must be greater than or equal to startDate");

var dates = new List<DateTime>();

for (var dt = start; dt <= end; dt = dt.AddDays(1))
{
    dates.Add(dt);
}
```

and now I need to filter them somehow in order to retrieve weekly results as I describe above but I am failing.

Do you have any ideas? Do you think my approach is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by _i am failing_ exactly? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: i cannot find the way to do it or i dont know if that way is the right  one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `List<List<DateTime>>` and adding checking of the week day in your loop like this:

```
        var dates = new List<List<DateTime>>();
        List<DateTime> weekDays = new List<DateTime>();
        for(var dt = start; dt<=end;dt=dt.AddDays(1))
        {

            if(dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday || DateTime.Compare(dt,start)==0)
            {
                weekDays.Add(dt);
            }
            else
            {
                weekDays.Add(dt);
                dates.Add(weekDays);
                weekDays = new List<DateTime>();
            }
        }
        if(weekDays.Count>0)
        {
            dates.Add(weekDays);
        }
```

And you will get list of lists like the following:

```
03.05.2017 00:00:00
04.05.2017 00:00:00
05.05.2017 00:00:00
06.05.2017 00:00:00
07.05.2017 00:00:00

08.05.2017 00:00:00
09.05.2017 00:00:00
10.05.2017 00:00:00
```